# homepage loading too slow

Tags: homepage

I transferred a website to VPS and when I open that website, the home page takes too long to load, for me its taking 30-35 secs just to display the home page, but when I navigate the internal pages it loads in normal speed,
I also tried this when all of my plugins were deactivated,
but no change, it was taking time to load.

Comment: what's your home page like? code? and does it have lots of DB calls?

Comment: its just a normal website, you can check this out, http://u-k.in

Comment: saying its just a normal website doesn't help. wheres the database, what else is happening on the server? what happens if you create a php page with lots of calls into a database, do you get slowdown? what happens when you install a cache, does this sort things out? what do your apache logs say?

Comment: @anu I mean to say that this website was not having any trouble in opening the homepage in previous shared hosting, when I transferred it to VPS, it suddenly started taking time in loading, and the word normal website means its just a basic info website not too many databases call are made, I have one more website on this VPS which works fine, so I don't think their is something wrong with VPS, their is some kind of problem with wordpress

Comment: @anu when I tried w3 total cache plugin it was taking more time to load, when I deactivated it took less time to load

Comment: given the previous questions and problems you've had, it's probably something wrong with your server setup. have you looked at your mysql setup ? slow queries? what are your logs telling you? how do you know not many database calls are made - wordpress by default makes a lot of calls to the database. do you have enough memory? As you can see, there are a huge number of things that could cause this - you're going to have to take a systematic approach to eliminating issues.

Comment: @anu so what should I try, I optimized the database through phpmyadmin, I have 101 tables in my database, and which logs to check apache log? my wp memory limit is 256 MB and php memory limit is 128 MB and its not full till yet, I am monitoring it through TPC plugin

Comment: I don't mean to be condescending, but you need to read up on basic server admin - perhaps move this question over to serverfault? The number of tables is probably immaterial. How much swap memory are you using? What happens if you take the other site offline? How much traffic are you getting? This question is just too broad to expect an answer - like i said, there are huge number of things that could cause this ranging from bad code in your theme to misconfigured apache/mysql/php

Comment: @anu Till now you just kept on saying you can do this, you can do that, but not a perfect answer, I am a newbie, thats why I asked over here, I am not asking for spoon feeding, but asked a suggestion what I have to do, and I am getting What I can do,
Anyways I appreciate your help, thanks for your time

Comment: Wow. There *is no perfect answer*. There are a LOT of things that might be wrong, none of which you seem to be willing to narrow down - giving you random suggestions is a waste of time. I've suggested several things to look at, none of which you seem to have looked at.

Comment: @anu As I said I am not looking for a perfect answer but a related close answer,
Thanks it was helpful and a nice piece of info I gathered the most important to post this question to serverfault,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a thread on wp-hackers in December which could be related: [Avoid query_post on frontpage on wp initialization](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-December/036960.html). You may give [Sergey Biryukov’s code](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-December/036963.html) a try:

> I was able to cancel the initial query with this code in the active theme's functions.php file:

```
function cancel_first_query() {
    remove_filter('posts_request', 'cancel_first_query');
    return '';
}
add_filter('posts_request', 'cancel_first_query');
```

Comment: is my question related to this? cause I just transferred from shared to VPS and started this website,

Comment: @ntechi I’m not sure; I just think it it may be possible. A good database cache could help too.

Comment: I tried w3TC but it gave bad results, it was taking more time in loading

Comment: @ntechi As long as you are logged in you don’t get cached pages. You have to log out to see a difference.

Comment: +1 on this. Just visited the link and got 4.7sec. for the whole front page/home.

Answer (score 0):

If your normal pages are loading quickly, the calls to the database are probably your culprit.

I would have a look at some caching options for your content. They'll render the page once as an HTML document for your logged-out visitors. Read the descriptions and see if they'll be a good fit:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/ 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-cache/

Answer (score 0):

Your site loads normally for me. It could be something with your own ISP too.
Also, try changing your theme and see if the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install FIrebug and myabe that YSlow script to see whats holding it up. GO to NEt tab and click ALL, it gives you load time of each dependency.

Sean
[Internet Marketing Guides](http://www.thejumpstarter.com)